# Translate collectionView to Swift to Configure the Custom Cell

Tags: iphone, swift, uicollectionview, nsdictionary, uicollectionviewcell

I have developed a Collection View app using Objective-C. I am now trying to recreate it using Swift, but I can't seem to translate these last two snippets of code.

**Can someone please help me translate my setupCell function in order to configure the Custom Cell?**

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as CollectionViewCell

    ###Translate to Swift
    cell setupCell:[self.titles.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)

    return cell
}

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

  ###Translate to Swift
  -(void)setupCell:(NSDictionary *)dictionary {
    NSString *imageFileName = [dictionary valueForKey:@"image"];
    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageFileName];

    self.nameLabel.text = [dictionary valueForKey:@"name"];

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this code:

```
 func setUpCell(dictonary:NSDictionary){

    var imageFileName : NSString = dictonary.valueForKey("image") as NSString
    self.imageView.image = UIImage(named:imageFileName)
    self.nameLabel.text = dictonary.valueForKey("name") as NSString

}
```

let me know if it works for you because I didn't test it

Comment: The function works :). would you know how to translate this too     
cell setupCell:[self.titles.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)

Comment: try this :self.setUpCell(self.title.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row))